# WPA2-PSK [AES] login asks only for password, but I need username & password to login

Tags: wifi-configuration, range

I'm trying to connect to a 2.4GHz Wi-Fi network using a Netgear WN2500RP range extender. I connect to the range extender and through its web portal try to connect it with a secure network I have access to. My usual access is with a username and password, but the range extender only prompts for a passeord when it tries to connect to this network. It's an institutional network so I don't have access to the network router or settings, only a weak signal and valid username-password auth.

Why is the range extender only prompting for a password and not a username? Any way to work around that, sending authentication with a username too, so the range extender can authenticate and connect to the network?

When I have a stronger signal on a Windows 10 PC, I'm prompted for a username and password upon connecting, not in a web portal after connecting.

Network properties as shown when connected on a PC:

```
Protocol: 802.11n
Security: WPA2-Enterprise
Sign-in type: Microsoft Protected EAP
Network band: 2.4GHz
Network channel: 1
Description (my network card I think): Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
```

Network properties shown in range extender web portal:

```
Security: WPA2-PSK
Channel: 1
```

I can connect to the network at a distant office with spotty but sometimes fully functional signal on my PC. I'm hoping I can use a range extender to improve the signal reliability. Maybe the range extender is incompatible and/or I need a different approach like a directional cantenna and external USB Wi-Fi adapter to improve the signal directly to my PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been looking at the [manual](https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WN2500RP/WN2500RP_UM_9Nov12.pdf) for your extender and it doesn't look like it supports WPA2-Enterprise. It only supports WPA2-PSK (pre-shared key) which is password authentication.

Comment: D'oh. That explains that. Off to get a different range extender I suppose. I'll leave the question open for a day in case someone has more thorough info to share but otherwise I'll accept this answer, thanks.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. I wish you luck in getting it sorted!